# Кодировки и класс nio.Charset

Tags: кодировка, java, utf-8

Насколько я понял, есть кодировки - это способ кодирования символов, такие как Unicode, они же UTF-8, UTF-16.

Также есть кодовые страницы - таблицы, в которых размещены символы, такие как ISO-8859-1, IBM-819.

И есть класс Charset.

Растолкуйте, какая взаимосвязь и что делает этот класс, и поправьте, если что неправильно.

Да и таблица символов есть своя Unicode, так это получается и таблица, и кодировка уже?

Или я могу предположить, что есть таблица Unicode со списком всех символов, которые он может кодировать. Но все символы, что в этом списке Unicode, разбиты на множество кодовых страниц. И Java, например, не содержит весь ассортимент этих страниц, а только какие-то там по умолчанию. И если мы хотим добавить или оперировать этими кодовыми страницами, то мы должны использовать класс Charset, правильно?
Т.е. получается, что Charset - это и есть кодовая страница?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode - это таблица символов (не кодировка), в которой каждому символу присвоен номер.

Кодировка - это способ представления каждого символа в машинном виде (т.е. какой последовательностью байтов кодируется символ). Например UTF-8 - это кодировка.

Подробнее о терминах можно прочитать в статье [Кодирование символов: Основные понятия](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/Overview.ru.php?changelang=ru).

Класс `Charset` позволяет оперировать текстом в определенной пользователем кодировке, а именно кодировать строки в набор байтов в заданной кодировке и декодировать набор байтов из заданной кодировки в строки.

Comment: В очередной раз спасибо.

Comment: Уточнение: я так понял, существует много кодировок, таких как ISO-8859, Windows-1250, КОИ8. И за каждой кодировкой закреплены свои таблицы символов. За UTF-8 закреплена таблица Unicode, в которой абсолютно все символы. Но так как UTF-8 не везде поддерживается, то приходиться пользоваться другими кодировками. Все верно?

Comment: @romashechka ISO-8859 и пр., всегда представляются одним байтом. В этом случае можно говорить что таблица и кодировка - это одно и то же.